# Rails - Table column width is being affected by select box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a table that seems to adapt to the longest text string in a given column.  I have select tags in each row which seem to be messing up the display.  There is an extra column being added to the table and the border on the right is not displaying.  If I shrink the size of the select tags, the table is formatted correctly, but I'd like to just have the table conform to the size of the largest select tags and largest buttons in the next column.  Thanks.  Here's the code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Allocation</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<% position_map = @cabinet.cabinet_position_map %>
<% @cabinet.cabinet_type.usize.downto(1) do |i| %>
<tr>
    <td>Slot: <%= i %></td>
    <% if position_map[i].nil? %>
        <% cabinet_device_selection = @cabinet.devices_to_fit(position_map, i) %>
        <% @selection_list = [ "Power", "I/O", "Interface", "Unusable", "Other", "Missing", "Reserve" ] %>
        <% cabinet_device_selection.each do |device| %>
            <% @selection_list << device.name %>
        <% end %>
        <% if position_map[i].nil? %>
                <%= form_tag( {:controller => :cabinets, :action => :update_device_position, :position => i , :id => @cabinet.id } , { :method => 'get', :class => "form-search" }) do %>
                    <td>
                        <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'position', i %>
                        <%= submit_tag "Add" , :class => "btn" %>
                    </td>
                <% end %>
        <% end %>               
    <% else %>
        <% position_map[i].each do |cabinet_item| %>
            <td>
                <%= cabinet_item.name %>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= link_to "Remove", { :controller => :cabinets, :action => :remove_cabinet_position, :id => @cabinet.id, :position => i}, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
            </td>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>   
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

And here's what the output looks like:

[image: Ill formatted image]

Comment: are u using any css? and is it possible to convert that ruby code to html and post it? I meant, you can get the html code for this ruby code by chrome developer tool

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Bootstrap.

So, to change the width of select_tag you can simply do.

```
    <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list), :class => "span1" %>
```

Or, if you want to set custom width, add a class in your css.

```
    .option-small {
       width: 100px !important;
    }
```

And then use

```
    <%= select_tag :position_name, options_for_select(@selection_list), :class => "option-small" %>
```

Comment: Hey Joe... Did it help? If yes, would you mind accepting the answer? :)